# How to calculate the advantage in policy gradient functions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, objective-functions, policy-gradients, reinforce

From my understanding of the REINFORCE policy gradient method, we gently nudge the probabilities of actions based on the advantages. More specifically, the positive advantages **increase** the probabilities, negative advantages **reduce** the probabilities.

So, how do we compute the advantages given the **real discounted rewards** (aggregated rewards from the episode) and a **policy network** that only outputs the probabilities of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us note the definition of the advantage function:

$$A(s,a) = Q(s,a) - V(s) \; ,$$

where $Q(s,a)$ is the action-value function and $V(s)$ is the state-value function. In theory you could represent these by two different function approximators, but this would be quite inefficient. However, note that 
$$Q(s,a) = \sum_{s',r} \mathbb{P}(s',r|s,a)(r + V(s') = \mathbb{E}[r + V(s')|a,s]\;,$$
so we can actually use a single function approximation, for $V(s)$, to completely represent the advantage function. To optimise this function approximator you would use the returns at each step of the episode as in e.g. the REINFORCE algorithm like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is basically a function of the actual return received and a baseline. The function of the baseline is to make sure that only the actions that are better than average receive a positive nudge.

One way to estimate the baseline is to have a value function approximator. At every step, you train a NN, using the trajectories collected via the current policy, to predict the value function for states.

I hope that answers your query.